# Is there a way I can apply eslint:all rules to an Angular app?

Tags: angular, eslint, eslintrc

Our convention was applying all the eslint rules available to our AngularJS project by extending
`"extends": ["eslint:all"]`. These rules now break my Angular code. Is there a way I can use all the eslint rules without breaking Angular?

We started using @angular-eslint

```
    "extends": [
                "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
                "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates",
                "plugin:prettier/recommended"
               ],
```

but these rules are not strict enough for me (also tried "plugin:@angular-eslint/all"). I have also tried [eslint-config-angular-strict](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-angular-strict) but it is not strict enough (e.g doesn't complain about console.logs).

Is there any way I can use eslint:all rules without breaking my application?

Comment: Sure, use "eslint:all", then carve out exceptions for the rules that Angular breaks.

Comment: Is there a specific list of them you know about? Or how would I curate the exceptions? @HereticMonkey

Comment: Well, they're listed in "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended" :). You're the one who wants a custom list of rules; you'd have to maintain them.